# Which language can I use, for these purposes?

Tags: operating-system

In any operating system, which programming language is the most oriented to perform actions, such as:

- Delete files from the computer
- Add files to the computer
- Unzip files automatically
- Having many files like 01file.jpg - 02file.jpg, rename them all automatically using regular expressions (this point is very important to me)

And many things like that, which include automating actions that are regularly very tedious to perform.

I do not need the most "appropriate" language, but the one that is generally used for these purposes.

Comment: C language is appropriate!

Comment: Any high level language that supports the listed operations gets the job done, but the question'd be closed because it is an opinion based one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choice of programming language is obviously a combination of technical factors and personal tastes. However, there are many strengths to Python for doing the tasks you mention in a way that is very portable between different operating systems. The "[os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)" module contains lots of functions for adding/removing files and directories, renaming files, etc. Similarly, the [regexp](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) module allows replacing chunks of strings using regular expressions. As for zipfiles, there's a module for that [too](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: Thanks, i will use python and c

Answer (score 0):

Any language can do these things really, so pick one that you’d want to learn. Python comes by default with lots of libraries, I believe including zip file manipulation, so it may be easier to get going.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I've inferred that you are looking for a language that is portable and easy to use with low friction in order to perform the operations that you mentioned.

If you mostly work with UNIX-based systems such as macOS and Linux, then shell programming might be a good option, especially considering the basic tasks you require.

The advantages of using the shell is that it's very well suited for the tasks you mention, you can easily alternate between automating your tasks with a shell script or just issuing commands as needed. The syntax can be a little bit surprising for beginners, but for your purposes, you wouldn't need to learn much.

The disadvantages are that there can be small but subtle differences between Operating Systems between commands, so you would need to know about these differences if working on these different platforms was important to you. Also, while you could get a shell like bash to work on Windows, it's nowhere near as convenient as on a UNIX-based OS.

If cross-platform compatibility was very important to you, then using a higher level general-purpose language like Python might be a good option. It has the advantage of being mostly consistent across platforms and abstracting away the differences.

The disadvantage there is that you might need to install Python depending on the platform that you have and you would lose a little bit of the interactivity and flexibility that the shell provides you with. On a UNIX-based machine, you're pretty much in a shell as soon as you fire up your terminal and ready to issue commands, so there is very little friction.